# Flask - Bad Request The browser sent a request that this server could not understand

Tags: python, parsing, flask

I am trying to make the prediction of the parser model, pre trained spacy model is used, i am using flask as an api and html as front end. But it is throwing an error of bad request.

```
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return flask.render_template('index.html')



@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])


def predict():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        image_file = request.files["file_image"]
 
nlp_model = spacy.load("nlp_model")

img2 = cv2.imread(image_file)
img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Tesseract- 
OCR\tesseract.exe'
out_below_1 = pytesseract.image_to_string(img_rgb,  
config=pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd)
tx = " ".join(out_below_1.split('\n')) 

doc = nlp_model(tx)
s = []

for ent in doc.ents:
    s.append(ent)

return  s

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: does it throw that error when You try to access `/index`? well two reasons for that (actually I don't know about one of them but...) first of You have two routes that are the same so flask won't know which one to use, second there should be no space between decorator and function definition

Answer (score 1):

Generally this error is due to access to a non-existent parameter within the `request` object. Try to print the content of the `request.files` object: `print(str(request.files))`, it probably does not contain a file called **file_image**.

Also pay attention to the definition of the routes, you have two different routes called **index**.

Comment: Actually , i have already changed the names of the routes , but i have come to know by changes that it is not containing an image file, it is getting passed empty thats why i am getting this error. So How to resolve this ?

Comment: It is a problem of how you are making the http call, surely you are doing something wrong there. Open another question to figure out what you are doing wrong, as this was about the `Bad Request` error